# Running .NET Core API Linux Environment Launch Profiles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

So I'm trying to get a .NET Core API application running with different environment settings.  I've been reading the documentation and as far as I can tell I've followed the instructions.  Yet when I run the service outside of VS it blows up due to not being able to find a connection string.  I'm clearly missing something basic.

I've setup two profiles in `launchSettings.json` "Development" and "Staging"

```
"profiles": {
  "IIS Express": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  },
  "Development": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
  },
  "Staging": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
    }
  }
```

I have the following configuration files.

```
appsettings.json
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.Staging.json
```

I also have the following code in in my `Startup.cs`:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()  
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

Configuration = builder.Build();
```

When I debug this I can see that `.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json"` is loading the expected file.  However, when I publish this to a directory and attempt to run it the `connectionString` value us `null`.

appsettings.json doesn't contain a value for the connection string. It is in the two environment dependent files, defined like:

```
"DefaultConnection": {
    "ConnectionString":
        "Server=name;Port=3307;Database=name;User Id=name;Password=name;"
},
```

Since this all works inside VS I'm sure this is all correct.  However when I try to run it, BOOM!

```
dotnet MyDll.dll --launch-profile Staging
```

I've just noticed that `--launch-profile` only works with `dotnet run` and that when I try to run the application it's looking for a `Production.json` file.  How do I use the various profiles with just the `dotnet` command, not the `dotnet run` command?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments explains it all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after some more poking around.  It seems that you have to set the environment variable on the server, I had mistakenly thought this was some kind of "runtime environment" variable, nope it's a full on OS level environment variable:

**LINUX**

export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging

**POWERSHELL**

$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Staging"

**WINDOWS**

set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging

Comment: That's  all in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging
only works for the current command shell

Answer (score 0):

In addition to set the environment variables (`AddEnvironmentVariables`), you can also use command line (`AddCommandLine`), here's an example:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateDefaultBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
        // ConfigureHostConfiguration is only for IHostingEnvironment currently
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

            if (args != null)
            {
                // e.g.: dotnet run --environment "Staging"
                config.AddCommandLine(args);
            }
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
        {
            var env = context.HostingEnvironment;
            builder.SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            if (args != null)
            {
                builder.AddCommandLine(args);
            }
        });

    return hostBuilder;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, could you explain it a bit more though?

Comment: From what I can tell this seems to only work with `dotnet run` commands.

Comment: I don't think it only works with `dotnet run` command. For more information, you can read this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1