# How to reference environment variables in launchsettings.json on linux

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core

I have configured a dev cert in my project. The cert path is in my `HOME` directory.

When I configure environment variable `ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path`, none of

```
$HOME/.aspnet/https/localhost.pfx
$(env:HOME)/.aspnet/https/localhost.pfx
${HOME}/.aspnet/https/localhost.pfx
```

works. Now I set it to `/home/nemo/.aspnet/https/localhost.pfx` and it can run normally.

I refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770206/is-it-possible-to-reference-environment-variables-in-launchsettings-json), but it seems to only work on PowerShell, while I use zsh.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set environment variables on the server:

```
**LINUX**

export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging

**POWERSHELL**

$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Staging"

**WINDOWS**

set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging
```

Reference document:

[**Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: It seems to be the configuration of the entire OS, but I only want to configure it for this project.

Comment: Do you want to configure the environment for this project separately in launchSettings.json? You can refer to the practice of this post, it may be helpful to you：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52883707/running-net-core-api-linux-environment-launch-profiles